# Read a collection of dates

Tags: c++

How to read a number of dates and store them in a array/vector in C++? For examples I have:

```
6
20 1 2014
25 3 2010
3 12 2001
18 11 2001
19 4 2015
9 7 2005
```

where 6 is the number of given dates. Each date is separated by a space.
This is my attempt:

```
std::cout << "Enter the number of dates to enter : ";
int num_dates;
std::cin >> num_dates;
    
std::vector<std::string> dates;
for ( int i= 0; i < num_dates; i++)
{
  std::cout << "Enter date number " << ii+1 << ": ";
  std::string date;
  getline( std::cin , date);
  dates.push_back(date);}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did your attempted implementation go wrong?

Comment: Although your attempt is not a [mcve], it appears to me that the snippet ought to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you don't want to separate the date to day, month and year, but just save it into array. My solution:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the number of dates to enter: ";
    int num_dates;
    std::cin >> num_dates;

    std::vector<std::string> dates;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num_dates; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter date number " << i << ": ";
        if (!(i - 1))
            std::cin.get();
        std::string date;
        std::getline(std::cin, date);
        dates.push_back(date);
    }
}
```

I added std::cin.get() when i = 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
// Just create a dates object which should store the dates as in the constructer 
// Create a arraylist of type dates to store them. 
class dates {

public:

    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

    dates(int day, int month, int year) {
        this->day = day;
        this->month = month;
        this->year = month;
    }

    int setDay(int day) {
        this->day = day;
    }

    int setMonth(int month) {
        this->month = month;
    }

    int setYear(int year) {
        this->year = year;
    }

    int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
};

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    std::list<dates> myDates = {};

    dates newDate = dates(20, 4, 2020);

    myDates.push_back(newDate);
   

}
```